# How can I re-use the same method in different classes when there is a extra action in one of them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have the following:

```
class A

  def do_something()
    ...
  end

end

class B

  def do_something()
    ...
    extra_action()
  end

end
```

In which `def do_something` methods have the same body except the extra_action(). In terms of clean code is there any way to place `def do_something` in a module and somehow inject the `extra_action` when in class B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're looking to do is to allow subclasses or classes that include a module to "tap into" the flow of the super method you can do it by using blocks and the `yield` keyword:

```
module A
  def do_something
    str = "Hello"
    yield(str) if block_given?
    str << " World"
  end
end

class B
  include A
  def do_something
    super { |str| str << " Brave" }
  end
end

class C
  include A
end

B.new.do_something # Hello Brave World

C.new.do_something # Hello World
```

One example where this is used is Devise where it lets you customize the controllers without reimplimenting the whole action:

```
class MyRegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    super do |resource|
      resource.frobnobize!
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you could create 2 modules, one for `do_something` and one for a decorator of `do_something`

```rb
module DoSomeThing
 def do_something
  # ...
 end
end

module DoSomeThingAndExtraAction
 include DoSomeThing
 
 def do_something
   super
   extra_action()
 end

 # you could override extra_action
 def extra_action
  # ...
 end
end
```

now you include module `DoSomeThing` to class `A`, and include module `DoSomeThingAndExtraAction` to class `B`

```rb
class A
 include DoSomeThing
end

class B
 include DoSomeThingAndExtraAction
 
 def extra_action
  # override
 end
end
```

you could separate `extra_action` into other modules and include to B what you want

```rb
module Extra1
 def extra_action
 end
end

module Extra2
 def extra_action
 end
end

class B
 include DoSomeThingAndExtraAction
 include Extra1
end

class C
 include DoSomeThingAndExtraAction
 include Extra2
end
```

Comment: The decorating module seems to be unnecessary. One could do it in the class directly.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev maybe i overthink OP'purpose :D , anyway, consider that i suggest another option for OP.